# How to manage PING replies?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, iptables, ping, icmp

How can I manage, for example, my Ubuntu mashine so it doesn't (or does) respond to [PING](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping_%28networking_utility%29)(ICMP ECHO_REQUEST - type 8) requests?

Normally almost all computers in a LAN network responds to ping with an ICMP ECHO_REPLY, but how to turn it off?

How to Manage it? How to manage other types [ICMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol) request?

Comment: Please explain your downvotes

Answer (score 1):

`/proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_all` set to a non zero number will not respond to IPv4 pings, IPv6 doesn't seem to have the same amount of options.

Other options and values can be found [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man7/icmp.7.html)

Answer (score 0):

For example `iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j DROP`. Same with other types...